# Unrar password protected file on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

So I created a .rar file on windows and it's password protected, and now I'm uploading it to a server, how can I unrar that file on the server to work with the password protected file.

I guess `tar -xzf`won't work

Comment: The tar command opens tar archives that may have been compressed with gzip, bzip2 or something else.  If you want to open a rar archive, then you need to use a tool that recognizes the rar format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install unrar or unrar-free

`sudo apt-get install unrar-free`

Then:

`unrar-free -x -p password file`